# BeagleBone Black reboots when connected with HDMI Display

Tags: beaglebone-black, hdmi

I am working on BeagleBone Black board (Debian running on it) and it is working fine. Now I want it's Linux GUI on screen, to do so I have connected BeagleBone Black with HDMI cable.

Now, when I power it up it displays boot log messages on screen but after displaying logs it automatically reboots.But if I am connecting HDMI display to BeagleBone Black after boot process is complete it works fine. It reboots when HDMI display is connected to it while powering it on.

I am using 5V-1A power supply as prescribed in Documentation of board.

I am unable understand why I am facing this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: I'm going to guess ground interference. Test the common-mode noise of your Beagle supply versus earth ground, to start with.

Comment: Most likely your power source is not capable of supplying the required amount of current at startup.

Comment: I have changed the display, it worked with 5v-2A and as well as with 5v-1A.